# Built in colormaps in Matlab

Tags: graphics, matlab, colors

I want a lighter version of the "cyan" color, using the function colormap('cyan'). How do you do this?

Comment: There is no built-in colormap called "cyan". Are you wanting to *create* your own colormap with shades of cyan?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the function [BRIGHTEN](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/brighten.html):

```
X = spiral(8);
image(X)
colormap(winter), colorbar
brighten(0.6)
```

Another trick is to right click on the colorbar and select **Interactive Colormap Shift**, this allows to shift the color-to-data mapping using mouse dragging.

[image: cmap_shift]

Comment: Neat! I didn't know about this feature. Is it new?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure, but a look at the Wayback machine indicates that it was available back in 2007: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http%3A//www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f0-41699.html

Answer (score 2):

Pure cyan is represented by the RGB triple `[0 1 1]`. To make it lighter, just increase the red component (ex: `[0.5 1 1]`), thus moving it closer to pure white (`[1 1 1]`). If you want to make a colormap that spans from pure cyan through lighter shades of cyan all the way to pure white, you can do the following:

```
nValues = 128;  %# The number of unique values in the colormap
map = [linspace(0,1,nValues)' ones(nValues,2)];  %'# 128-by-3 colormap
```

Now you can set the colormap to the one made above using the [COLORMAP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) function:

```
colormap(map);
```

For more discussion of colors in MATLAB, check out [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me `colormap('cyan')` fails because `cyan` is undefined.

However, you can create your own colors easily.  If cyan is equivalent to `[0,1,1]` a lighter color would be `[0,1,1] + [.1,0,0] = [.1,1,1]` or rather just increase the R in RGB to increase the luminosity.