# colormap in matlab

Tags: matlab, colors

For a colormap how do you accentuate the brightness of some of the dimmer features?

Comment: similar question: [Built in colormaps in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785717/built-in-colormaps-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [BRIGHTEN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/brighten.html) function to brighten the *entire* colormap, thus brightening the dimmer features as well:

```
brighten(0.5);  %# Brightens the current colormap

%# OR...

newMap = brighten(oldMap,0.5);  %# Brighten the colormap in variable oldMap
colormap(newMap);               %# Update the current colormap to newMap
```

If you want to brighten *only* the dimmer features (i.e. just *part* of the colormap), you have to first decide how to classify what counts as a "dimmer" feature. ;)

Comment: +1 another interesting function is CONTRAST: given an image, it create a grayscale colormap that enhances the contrast http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/contrast.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have a grayscale colormap, the grayvalues map linearly to the intensities. In order to enhance dim features, you want the low intensities to be mapped onto a larger range of grayvalues than the high intensities. In other words, you stretch the low intensities and compress the high intensities. This can be done by adjusting the [gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) of the colormap. Of course you can do a gamma correction for RGB colormaps as well.

If you have the image processing toolbox, the Matlab command for this is [IMADJUST](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imadjust.html), which you use like this:

```
newColormap = imadjust(oldColormap,[low_in; high_in],[low_out; high_out],gamma);
```

The new colormap maps the values in the range low_in/high_in to the range low_out/high_out - so you most likely want to use minimum/maximum of the colormap - and gamma is what you want to set to >1.

An alternative, quick way to emphasize dim features is to display the square root (or, for a more pronounced effect, the logarithm) of your image.

```
imshow(sqrt(img),[])
```

Comment: +1: IMADJUST is a good option, assuming of course that you have the Image Processing Toolbox. ;)

Comment: @gnovice: thanks, I clarified the solution - though I personally tend to use the square root or log for emphasis. It's a lot quicker and requires less fiddling.