# changing the color span of a colormap in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

how I change the span of a gray colormap from 0-255 to 100-255 in a mesh/surf graph? I wonder if this can be done without converting the data to uint8.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464484/colormap-in-matlab/3466995#3466995) by Jonas

```
newColormap = imadjust(oldColormap,[low_in; high_in],[low_out; high_out],gamma);
```

but I don't know how to assign the variable "colormap gray" to "oldColormap"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your mesh/surf is using indexed [`CData`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surface_props.html#zmw57dd0e357960) with `CDataMapping` set to scaled, then you can control the limits of the color mapping using [CAXIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/caxis.html). Example:

```
surf(peaks)
colormap gray, colorbar
caxis([-2 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

`gray` is already a defined variable in matlab. So all you have to do is:

```
>> imadjust(gray,[0; 1],[100/255; 1])

ans =

    0.3922    0.3922    0.3922
    0.4018    0.4018    0.4018
    0.4115    0.4115    0.4115
    0.4211    0.4211    0.4211
    0.4308    0.4308    0.4308
    0.4404    0.4404    0.4404
    ...
```

Comment: Hi John Colby, I`m doing something wrong because the program does not obey me. I show you my program:`ang5=ang5-min(min(ang5));
ang5=ang5./max(max(ang5));
h5=surf(x5,y5,ang5);view(0,90);shading interp;axis tight equal off; colormap gray
imadjust(h5,[0; 1],[0; 1], 90);`