# Colour specific bins in histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

Let's say I have something like:

```
A = randi(30, [10, 1]);
hist(A)
```

and I want to change the colour of the bins that are below certain value (say 3) to red, while leaving the others blue or other dark colours (not important). How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html) to assist you:

```
A = randi(30, [10, 1]);
[N, X] = hist(A);                      %# Extract bin values and positions
idx = N < 3;                           %# Indices of values less than threshold
figure, bar(X, N), hold on             %# Plot histogram in default color
bar(X(idx), N(idx), 'facecolor', 'r')  %# Plot red bars on top
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: sorry the question was phrased wrongly. I meant the leftmost x number of bars. *edit* I changed the 3rd line to idx= X < 3 and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create your own [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) for use in plotting the data.  That way you can define when you want what color to be used.

You should be able to figure out how to make your own colormap matrix, but if you are still stuck later just pop the code up here and we can take a gander at it.

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464484/colormap-in-matlab` that might help you out a bit too.